# Display D3 javascript codes stored on DB based in xhtml page based on user selections

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, primefaces

I will store many D3 script in a DB and will display the resulting graphics in my application. When the user selects a visualization type which corresponds to a D3 script I want to add that script to the code and arrange my data in a suitable format (for that specific script) and form the xhtml.

My plan was having a template xhtml which is nearly empty, only having a div section. The scripts should be added to this xhtml on runtime using something like below expression. 
The application is a Java Spring JSF application and Primefaces library is used for the user interfaces.

```
#{selectedScriptTextualContent}.
```

I am not sure how this solution should be implemented. Is there anyone who may offer a sophisticated solution which will work?

Regards,
Ferda

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking and how this is jsf related

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Ok, clear now. Did you **try** inluding the scripts in the way you suggest above

Comment: Yes I did.  I tried as this one and as  below. Both of them didn't work :( <h:panelGroup >
            <span id="example1"></span>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputScript >
            document.getElementById('example1').innerHTML = '#{dashboardController.selectedVisualizationScript}';
        </h:outputScript>